# How can i detect specific RTL features at compile time?

Tags: delphi, portability, conditional-compilation

For sake of example lets check for infamous `TStrings.StrictDelimiter`:

```
{$IF Declared(TStrings.StrictDelimiter)}
{$MESSAGE WARN 'Beware of TStrings.StrictDelimiter which is False by default!'}
{$IFEND}
```

However, `Declared` compiler intrinsic reports syntax error on conditional line: `E2029 ')' expected but '.' found`. (tested on XE)

Comment: This feature is not supported by the `{$IF declared()}` but exist a [QC](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=11009) where you can vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this kind of expressions aren't supported, you have to know in which RTL / compiler version some feature was introduced and then use [predefined conditional symbols](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_%28Delphi%29) like `VER<nnn>`, `RTLVersion`, [CompilerVersion](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiler_Versions) etc.

Comment: This raises the other question: is there a list(s) of RTL/VCL features, which can hurt portability along the Delphi compiler line?

Comment: AFAIK no list, but some information can be found ie http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Category:Cross-Platform . Also compiler emits warning for platform specific stuff (if you don't turn it off, see for example http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/W1002_Symbol_%27%25s%27_is_specific_to_a_platform_%28Delphi%29).

Answer (score 2):

For Delphi XE2 I'm using this :

```
{$IFDEF BDS9}
  Result.VersionString := 'Delphi XE2 ' +
  {$IF NOT DECLARED(Consts.SStyleFeatureNotSupported)}
    '(original release version)'
  {$ELSE} {$IF NOT DECLARED(FireMonkeyVersion)} // D2010 chokes when scope (FMX.Types) is mentioned!
    'Update 1'
  {$ELSE} {$IF NOT DECLARED(System.TestSSE)}
    'Update 2'
  {$ELSE}
    'Update 3'
    // TODO : Update this for any following update!
  {$IFEND} {$IFEND} {$IFEND}
  ;
{$ELSE}
  {$IFDEF BDS7}
     Result.VersionString := 'Delphi 2010';
  {$ELSE}
    {$MESSAGE ERROR 'Extend this!'}
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
```

In other words : I test for the existence of symbols that are introduced since any particular delphi-version. The same construct can be used to set a variable or constant or compiler define, so further code can use these instead.

Note : I keep a backup around of the `Source` folder for all Delphi versions that I've had installed in the past few years. Putting these folders through a tool like BeyondCompare and browsing through the differencing files, will quickly give you a few symbols that you can test for....